# What are all the possible first-words of SQL statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, ado

I'm building a user interface to be able to execute SQL statements on a SQL Server database, compatibility at SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to be able to determine whether each statement could possibly return a dataset, or if it just needs to be executed. In Delphi, the `TADOQuery` consists of either `Open` / `Close` for a dataset, or `ExecSQL` just to execute. I need to automatically determine which one to use based on the first word(s) of the SQL statement.

How can I determine which method I should call based on the first word(s) in the statement? I would need to know each possible word, and which method based on each word.

Comment: Let's not downvote because we know the answer is "you can't". It's a legitimate question.

Comment: My guess is that SELECT returns rows, whereas other commands *may* return data. Otherwise, you will need to prepare the statement, and see from the result column definition if there is some data to retrieve. Let the DB engine parse the SQL for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not possible in the general sense. EXEC stored-procedure-name for example can eithers return a result set or not, depending on how the proc is written. There is no way to know if it's one or the other just from the syntax of the call.

Comment: To add to that, even `update`/`delete`/`insert` may return rows if coupled with `output`.

Comment: And `WITH` can be a prefix to either a query or a DML statement.

Comment: A stored procedure could return more than one result set.

Comment: @HABO Well the `TADOQuery` in Delphi only supports a single dataset, not multiple. And I already have the parsing part down, I can separate different statements. I'm just troubled at identifying how to handle each statement.

Comment: Maybe a  *very* brute force approach would be to try 'Open' and catch/suppress any errors. The possible errors telling you that the query does not return a dataset would be a limited number...

Comment: @Jerry, no, you can use [`NextRecordset`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.NextRecordset) method to work with multiple recordsets (resultsets, or as you call datasets). Anyway, I'm missing the reason for this question. You need to know if a certain query or a stored procedure returns something - moreover, you need to know what it returns, if something, because you will work with those data later on. Interesting topic on the other hand! [+1]

Comment: The tricky part is sorting out each separate statement, along with GO, each GO statement requires its own block handling. ADO in Delphi just simply doesn't support GO.

Comment: @JerryDodge - SQL Server T-SQL doesn't "support" `GO`. `GO` is implemented as part of SSIS, iSQL etc. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx. T-SQL uses `;` to determine end of statement.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm dividing each statement based on `GO` and executing them separately. I didn't describe all these details in my question because it's irrelevant.