# 'Open' or 'ExecSQL' detect query difference before executing

Tags: delphi, absolute-db

There are some queries that need to use the 'Open' command and some the 'ExecSQL'.

I am using the memo for my queries (first time)

```
Query1.SQL.Text := ADVMemo1.Lines.Text;
```

and cant figure out how to handle the mentioned difference
on button click.

Is there a way to check this when button is pressed so it knows what to apply?
Like... if query begins with insert or update then exec else ...

Comment: What datatype is your Query1?

Comment: not sure what you mean...

Comment: try the StartsText() function. But I think it's a bad Idea what you're doing. You should always make explicit what you're getting back from the database and now you have a buttonclick that can give back a dataset, or not.

Comment: I mean, what TDataSet-descendant type is Query1?  Look where it is declared on your form or datamodule.  Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: its an absolute database query ...ABSQuery1: TABSQuery; Nothing much ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This routine will check if the SQL starts with a `select` statement and if it does, it will open it, otherwise it will execute it.

```
procedure OpenOrExecute(Query: TABSQuery);
var Command: string;
begin
  Command := LowerCase(Copy(Trim(Query.Sql.Text), 1, 6));
  if Command = 'select' then
  begin
    Query.Open;
  end
  else
  begin
    Query.ExecSQL;
  end;   
end;
```

Now you can use it to open/execute a Query at any moment. example:

```
OpenOrExecute(Query1);
```

Although this would only work for very simple queries, for example stored procedures called with an `exec` command may or may not return a recordset. there is no way to know it from the SQL command alone.

Comment: @user3351050 You should read the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927761/what-are-all-the-possible-first-words-of-sql-statements). Parsing the input text is not fail-safe.

Comment: I would go the other way around, and check if the query starts with `SELECT` (after trimming the SQL text) => `.Open`. otherwise `.ExecSQL`. there could be many more SQL statements which might or might not return recordset. this might be sufficiant for absolute-database but will fail for db such as MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Much easier (and faster) if you reverse it and only check for `SELECT` (or `select`, if you prefer). What about a stored procedure that returns a rowset?

Comment: @Kobik The other way around is also problematic, because for example on SQL Server executing an Stored Prod (exec XXXX) may also return a recordset. As Jan said there is no way to know for sure (going back to the stored procedure, an exec command may or may not return recordsets). This routine would only work for very simple queries, which seems to be the case.

Comment: Anyway, as it seems to be preferred, I will change it to rather check for a SELECT.

Comment: "The other way around" was to check for a `SELECT`. I did not mentioned `EXEC` which of course is an issue. but I don't think abs-db supports SP.  *"You should already know if each Query is a command or a select..."* - OP is getting the query text from a Memo - this could be any statement, including CREATE/ALTER/DROP/EXEC etc...

Comment: You are right, and following your comment that's the modification I've made: to check for a SELECT. The EXEC was just an example of a query returning a recordset and not starting with SELECT, I can easily think of others, like commands starting with a comment, so instead of SELECT your SQL.Text will first find a /* or --

Comment: actually, I was using this just for learning sake.  I saw few examples on components ace site where they used memo for the queries. Then I run into the issue where I needed to tell my button what type of query am I executing. Thats why I asked because I never used memo for the query in my life. Also I think the answer was pretty good so I don't understand how can someone down-vote it. It checks the first 6 characters which are quite unique.This is simple database  not sql server or oracle. Also SELECT command falls into 'Open' thing, does it not ?